# How to receive a packet UDP with a known destination MAC different to that of the listening interface

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I am trying to listen for a specific discovery packet that will be sent over UDP destined for a known MAC address. This MAC address will not be the same as the MAC address of the interface I am receiving on.

I have tried Beej's [UDP listener](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#datagram) but it only receives packets with the correct MAC.

When I listen with tcpdump I can see the packets are making it to the device.

It looks like I could receive on a raw socket (although haven't got that working yet) but would there be a way to filter only the destination MAC I want?

Can anyone give me any guidance with this?

Answer (score 3):

Your interface does not normally receive packets that are not sent to its own address. It just ignores them.

You need to set your network interface in [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) and use a packet capture interface provided by Linux.

Have a look at [libpcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap), the manual page is [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html).

This is the same mechanism that *tcpdump* uses. It is a library which provides an interface and a filter to the packet capture mechanism in the kernel.

Comment: There is also a small section of relevant information in the same document that you referred to: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#indexId434909-212